# Explain Lenz Law with Conservation of Energy

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, electromagnetic-induction

My question is: If the bar magnet is moved towards a coil connected to a galvanometer and instead of a opposing magnetic pole a attractive pole i.e. south of coil and north of magnet is created due to induced emf in coil then how is Conservation of energy violated/ perpetual motion body created? Isn't it similar of having two bar magnets with attractive poles ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conservation of energy in Lenz's law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56062/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is an attractive force (N attracting S) no work has to be done to move the magnet and the magnet will get "sucked" into the coil all on its own.
Whilst this was happening due to the change of magnetic flux linked with the coil and emf will be induced (Faraday) and a current will flow which might heat the wires.
So there is a magnet moving into the coil without any help, possibly gaining kinetic energy and heat is generated in the coil - ie energy is being created but none is being expended.